# Radius-4 circle skewered on one line and touching another

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the circle with radius $4$ units, whose centre lies on the line $4x+13y=32$ and which touches the line $4x+3y+28=0$.

*My Approach*:
Radius $r=4$ units
Let $P(h,k)$ be the centre of the circle. Then $4h+13k=32$.

Please help me to move further.

Comment: Given the center, can you write the equation for the circle?  You can use the line to eliminate $h$ or $k$ from that.  Say you eliminate $k$.  Now, viewing $h$ as a parameter, solve the circle equation simultaneously with $4x+3y+28=0$  You need to choose $h$ so this solution has a double root, which means the square root in the quadratic equation is zero.

Comment: ##Ross Millikan, I could not get that. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4x+13y=32\iff \dfrac y4=\dfrac{8-x}{13}=m$(say)

So, any point on $4x+13y=32$ will be $(8-13m,4m)$

Now the perpendicular distance of $(8-13m,4m)$ from $4x+3y+28=0$ will be $$\dfrac{|4(8-13m)+3(4m)+28|}{\sqrt{4^2+3^2}}$$ which needs to be $=$ radius i.e., $4$ unit

Comment: what do I do after finding $m$?

Comment: @NeWtoN, Then we get $(x,y)$ i.e., the center.

Comment: @@lab bhattacharjee, does this " any point " indicates centre?

Comment: @NeWtoN,   Only the center will satisfy  "radius=perpendicular distance"  See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Radius_at_Right_Angle_to_Tangent

Comment: @@lab, Ok. Thank You very much.

Comment: @@##lab bhattacharjee,  while using the perpendicular distance formula,  you used $-32$ in place of constant,  I am confused whether it should be $-32$ or $+28$?

Comment: @NeWtoN, Thanks for your observation.

Comment: @@lab bhattacharjee, I think there is one more, is it $\sqrt {4^2+13^2}$ or $\sqrt {4^2+3^2}$? please do check.. ..

Comment: @NeWtoN, Checked. Please feel free to rectify my typo-s.

Comment: @@lab bhattacharjee, I understood your solution, but why is it sure that $(8-13m,4m)$ will definitely be the centre of circle?

Comment: @NeWtoN, First of all, I have derived $(8-13m,4m)$ is a parametric point on $4x+13y=32$ Now we know the perpendicular distance for the center of a circle to any tangent is equal to the radius of the circle

Comment: @@lab bhattacharjee, what is parametric point? I am not familiar with this term. Please explain..

Comment: @NeWtoN, For any real finite value of $m,(8-13m,4m)$ will lie on $4x+13y=32$  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParametricEquations.html

Comment: @@lab bhattacharjee, Ok I agree that $(8-13m,4m)$ lies on the line. But why will it exactly be the centre of circle?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a circle with center in $(a,b)$ and radius $4$ is
$$
\left( {x - a} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {y - b} \right)^{\,2}  = r^{\,2}  = 16
$$
Now you must have
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  4a + 13b = 32\quad \text{(center}\,\text{on}\,\text{the}\,\text{line}\,(\text{a))} \hfill \\
  4x + 3y + 28 = 0\quad \text{(point}\,\text{on}\,\text{the}\,\text{line}\;\text{(b))} \hfill \\
  \left( {x - a} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {y - b} \right)^{\,2}  = 16\quad \text{(point}\,\text{on}\,\text{the}\,\text{circle)} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
Now, from the first express e.g. $a$ in function of $b$, and from the second e.g. $y$ in function of $x$ and place them in the third. You will get 
$$\left( {x - 8 - \frac{{13}}
{4}b} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( { - \frac{{28}}
{3} - \frac{4}
{3}x - b} \right)^{\,2}  = 16
$$
Expand as a quadratic equation in $x$ and impose to have two coincident solutions, i.e. find $b$ such that the discriminant be $0$.
You will find two values, corresponding to whether the circle is on one side or the other with respect to the crossing point of the two lines.
Use each value of $b$ to determine the corresponding $x$, $y$, $a$.

Answer (score 1):

1. From L :4x + 3y + 28 = 0, get $\alpha (= 53.13^0$, but not really necessary). Note further that the blue triangle is a 3-4-5 right triangle.
2. Find G where L cuts the y-axis. OG is then known.
3. L’ is normal to L and passes through G. The angle between L’ and the y-axis = $\beta = \alpha$.

[image]

4. A point on the red line will be the center of the required circle. It will cut the y-axis at T, whose co-ordinates are to be determined.
5. The blue and green triangles are similar. Therefore, TG is known (using the 3-4-5 properties).
6. Find OT and therefore $T = … = (0, \dfrac {-8}{3})$.
7. Form the equation of Q which passes through T and has the same slope as L.
8. Solve P and Q to get X which is the center of the required circle.
9. ...

Answer (score 0):

Anypoint of the line $4x+13y=32$ have the form $(x,\frac{-31}{100}x+\frac{246}{100})$ and anypoint of the line $4x+3y=-28$ have the form $(x,\frac{-133}{100}x-\frac{933}{100})$. Now need calculate the distance of the point $(x,\frac{-31}{100}x+\frac{246}{100})$ to the point $(x,\frac{-133}{100}x-\frac{933}{100})$, use the euclidean distance equation:
$$\sqrt{(x-x)^2+(\frac{-31}{100}x+\frac{246}{100}-(\frac{-31}{100}x+\frac{246}{100}))^2}=4$$
Finding $x$:
$$x=-\frac{1579}{102} \lor x=-\frac{779}{102}$$
So exist 2 circles with center in the line $4x+13y=32$ and radius 4 that touch the line $4x+3y=-28$.
To find the equations of the circles you need replace the $x$ that we find in the line $4x+13y=32$ for get the center points, and use the equation $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$

Comment: how did you get the point i.e, $(x,....)$?

Comment: @user35073 clears $y$

Comment: I could not understand, what do you mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: If i clears $y$ of the equation $4x+13y=32$ i get $y=-\frac{31}{100}x+\frac{246}{100}$, then everypoint $(x,y)$ that is in the line $4x+13y=32$ is $(x,-\frac{31}{100}x+\frac{246}{100})$ (replace $y$)

Comment: And, what is.Euclidean Distance Equation?

Comment: @user354073, The distance between two points and  equaled to 4 for hypothesis

Comment: @testpilot, you messed up: if the first has the form $(x,\frac{-31}{100}x+\frac{246}{100})$ the second shall be $(x',\frac{-133}{100}x'-\frac{933}{100})$. They should be **independent** and not with the same abscissa !

Comment: @GCab i take a case

Comment: @testpilot, I deem you have better and delete your answer: it is completely misconceived ! you have found two points, one per line, at the same abscissa, having distance $4$.